# Java Object is converting into String in preprocessor of Mirth?

Tags: java, xml, marshalling, mirth

i passed the java object into the mirth in `preprocessor` phase , i want to marshal this java object to XML for that i have written custom java class for marshaling and i made  this java class as a jar and deployed in custom lib folder of the Mirth. The incoming message while logging showing java object(@something hash-code) in mirth but mirth is converting this object into String. But my requirement is to get the object as it is or is there any way to convert String represented object into actual custom java object which i have passed to mirth in `preprocessor` phase. This is the java class i have written for marshaling.

```
  public class JAXBMarshalling {


    public  void marshallJavaObjectToXml(OrderDetails orderDetails) {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext;
        try {
            File file = new File(
                    "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mirth Connect\\conf\\xml\\xmlrepresentation.xml");
            jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(OrderDetails.class);
            Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
            // output pretty printed
            jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(orderDetails, file);
            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(orderDetails, System.out);
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I quite understood your question. Basically there are two possible scenarios – when you are trying to pass the object within the channel or between channels; and when you are trying to pass the object as a part of a message to an external destination.

In first case you have to use the Global Channel Map since other two maps are persisted to the database and therefore Mirth Connect converts them to the string. In the second case try using <![CDATA[ ... ]]> to inform the parser what section to ignore.

As a follow up I would suggest the [Unofficial Mirth Connect Developer’s Guide](http://mirthconnect.shamilpublishing.com) where these scenarios are both mentioned. (Disclaimer: I’m the author of this book.)